# the android studio instantly remove my copy & paste import statement

Tags: android, android-studio

i've a project (blank activity) set up by android studio 0.8x, but when i paste (ctrl + v) some import statement like the following

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

the android studio will automatically rollback (ctrl + z) and only default import statement will stay, so i can't use any custom import statement  now, what the matter is going on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can control the behaviour in Settings, Editor, Auto-Import. It is the "optimize imports on the fly" setting

However, I would recommend to start writing your code, Android Studio will highlight the classes you have not yet imported and then you can add the necessary imports by simply typing Alt+Enter

Comment: The point is that the "optimize imports on the fly" is actually doing its job removing all those imports that are not really useful to the program at the moment of pasting them. In other words this optimize feature will remove the imported packages/classes that are unused till that moment. So, as other people said, better to start coding and use Alt+Enter to "add these dependencies on the fly" whenever they will become really needed

Answer (score 2):

when you import any file and immediate remove just follow below step in android studio and change this setting ...

> 1. press shift key two times continuously it will open **search everywhere** box
> 2. Type **Auto import** in this box. and result show **auto import**,click on this.
> 3. There is one option **Optimize imports on the fly** under the name **JAVA**,in your case it is checked..unchecked it and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Note: When you bring up the Search Everywhere box, there is a gear icon in the upper right with some settings. "Show IDE settings" must be turned ON for this to work.