# Android Studio auto import static variable and getting freeze for few seconds

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.2.2, and when I paste a static variable name from the clipboard to an Activity, Android Studio will be freeze for a few seconds and then auto-import the static variable.

For example, this is an auto-import: LIST_ONE_DETAILS is a URL(String) which is defined in URLManager:

```
import static com.XXXX.URLManager.LIST_ONE_DETAILS;
```

this is the definition in the URLManager:

```
public static final String LIST_ONE_DETAILS ="xxxx";
```

So, how to avoid the freeze, or how to disallow Android Studio to auto-import the static variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows/Linux, you can go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java and make the following changes:

change Insert imports on paste value so that it doesn't include Static variables. You may have to turn it all off.

Comment: I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135907/the-android-studio-instantly-remove-my-copy-paste-import-statement, go to Settings, Editor, Auto-Import. unselect "optimize imports on the fly"